# Issue in Typeahead

Tags: angularjs

I am facing an issue with **angular Typeahead**. As soon as user starts typing , I am calling a restful service and from the REST response I am creating a string which is a combination of **"name + person id + city + phone"** , which should be then displayed at the UI as suggestion.

I am able to invoke the RESTful service successfully and from the response I am creating a list of string which looks like this

```
 ["Tom,Alison ,00017556,Dulles,9988776655",
  "alice,Ali,00114088,Dulles,9988776655",
  "Vipin,Nambi,00034585,Dulles,9988776655",
  "David,Alison,00091141,Dulles,9988776655"
]
```

I am also able to print it using console.log but I don't see anything on UI. I tried to invoke another open source REST service "http://gd.geobytes.com/" and it's working fine and I can see the list of cities in the UI[please see the commented code]. I tried to print the response.data from geoBytes service and it looks like this on the console

```
Alice, TX, United States,
Aliceville, AL, United States,
Alicia, AR, United States,
Alief, TX, United States,
Aline, OK, United States,Aliquipp
```

and like this on browser

```
JSON_CALLBACK(["China Grove, NC, United States","China Spring, TX, United States","China, ME, United States","China, TX, United States","East China, MI, United States","South China, ME, United States"]);
```

I am unable to understand if it's working for geoBytes REST service then what's wrong with my service. I suspect that there is something wrong with how I am returning the data using limitToFilter(JSON.stringify(searchedPersonList ) but I am unable to resolve it. Can anyone please help me here.

**index.html**

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="result" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in person($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue">
```

**controller**

```
 $scope.person = function(searchString) {

    PersonDataService.getPersonForSearchString(searchString)
    .then(function (data)
    {
     var searchedPersonList = [];

    for(var i=0;i <data.SearchPersonResponse.Person.length ;i++ )
    {

    searchedPersonList .push( data.SearchPersonResponse.Person[i].FullName  + "," + 
data.SearchPersonResponse.Person[i].PersonID  + "," +

data.SearchPersonResponse.Person[i].City + "," +

data.SearchPersonResponse.Person[i].Phone  );

    }
    console.log ("The list prepared is " +JSON.stringify(searchedPersonList ));

    return limitToFilter(JSON.stringify(searchedPersonList ) , 15);
    },

    function (error)
    {
     alert("Invocation of REST service failed " + error.data);
    });



       /*
        This works

    return $http.jsonp("http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCitycallback=JSON_CALLBACK&filter=US&q="+searchString)
    .then(function(response)
    {
    console.log("geoBytes " + response.data);
    return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
    });

    */

    };
```

Comment: `return PersonDataService...` -- put a `return` in front of your service call. Keep the `return` in the callback as well

Comment: @tymeJV  - I tried this. It doesn't work.                                 $scope.person = function(searchString) {
return PersonDataService.getPersonForSearchString(searchString).then(function (data)

Comment: What does happen? Is the request coming back?

Comment: nothing happens on UI side. Same issue as earlier.

Comment: in the response from GeoBytes service , why there are no quotes to differentiate different entries? My response has double quotes , is that an issue?

Comment: Can you post your service?

Comment: @tymeJV - you were right. I have to use return twice but that was not the only problem. I also made the mistake of returning JSON.stringify(searchedPersonList ). I need to just return searchedPersonList. If you could suggest this in an answer , I can accept it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help! Glad ya figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to return the entire service call, add `return` before your service:

```
return PersonDataService.getPersonForSearchString(searchString)....
```

Also, return your non-stringified object as you mentioned in the comments (`searchedPersonList`)

Comment: could you please explain why I need to return twice. I come from Java background and it's weird for me.